# How can I put a button on the middle of the page?

Tags: javascript, css, button

Im having problems putting a button on the middle of the page!

I tried to search on youtube, google and stackoverflow, but I didn´t find anything!

```
<style>
        .firebaseui-auth-container {
            width: 1500px;
            height: 1500px;
            text-align: center;
            margin:0 auto;

        }
</style>
```

I tried to do the code that I mention but it dint´t work http://prntscr.com/n3u878 (as you can see)

Comment: What happens if your user's browser window *isn't* 1500px wide/high? How's that supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, this code positions the button with class `button-centered` at center of any container, in this case, an element with class `firebaseui-auth-container`

```
<style>
        .firebaseui-auth-container {
            width: 1500px;
            height: 1500px;
            text-align: center;
            margin:0 auto;
            position:relative;
        }
        .firebaseui-auth-container .button-centered{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
        }

</style>
```

Comment: Nothing changed!

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a simple css snippet to show one of the multiple approaches depending on what the rest of your requirements are.

```css
.centerButton {
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  width: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button class="centerButton">Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
```